# Cannot read property 'call' of undefined when making a change

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, livereload

- Ionic Framework: 3.4.2
- Ionic Native: ^2.9.0
- Ionic App Scripts: 2.1.3
- Angular Core: 4.1.3
- Angular Compiler CLI: 4.1.3
- Node: 6.11.0
- OS Platform: Windows 10
- Navigator Platform: Win32
- User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36

everything was working just fine until i install ionic-native, every time i make a change it shows me this error.

`Runtime Error
Cannot read property 'call' of undefined`

so i need to re-run ionic serve everytime i make a change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience, this error is usually the result of running multiple "ionic server" on the same machine. Double check you're not running in another terminal window.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to see for which function call you are getting error.
As per the error, the Function you are trying to call is undefined hence you can't call "call" method on it.

e.g. `myFun.call(myCtx, arg1, arg2,...);`
in your case myFun is undefined

Comment: it tells me that the function is in main.ts, but there is no function called call in this file

Comment: "call" is an api available on function, function name must be something else.
try searching for ".call" in your main.ts and put break point on each of this method call to see where  the actual error is.

Comment: FWIW, this presented for me in a very similar manner to the OP - after the first change.  I traced it to vendor.js:

```
function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {
...
modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);
...
```

Called by:
```
var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__ionic_native_native_storage__ = __webpack_require__(203);
```

This problem presented intermittently for me - I could recover from it by making another change.  Typically this means the order of some tasks runs a different order due to timing (non sequential order tasks).  HTH